# Método replace no funciona en texto con acento en Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Tengo un código en Python usando Pandas en donde quiero reemplazar el texto "Otros Bienes Jurídicos Afectados (Del Fuero Común)" por "Other Affected Legal Assets (Common Jurisdiction)", intenté con la línea
`comp['Affected Legal Good'].replace({'Patrimonio': 'Heritage', 'Familia':'Family', 'Libertad y Seguridad Sexual':'Sexual Freedom and Safety', 'Sociedad':'Society', 'Vida e Integridad Corporal':'Life and Bodily Integrity', 'Libertad Personal':'Personal Freedom', 'Otros Bienes Jurídicos Afectados (Del Fuero Común)':'Other Affected Legal Assets (Common Jurisdiction)'}, inplace=True, regex=True)`

Sin embargo, me funciona con todos los reemplazos menos ese, de igual manera intenté quitar los acentos con:

`comp['Affected Legal Good'].str.normalize('NFKD').str.encode('ascii', errors='ignore').str.decode('utf-8')`

Pero no funciona y el texto sigue igual.

Comment: ¿Puedes proporcionar una muestra de tus datos donde aparezca ese problema? Para poder hacer pruebas y experimentos con él y tratar así de comprender qué está pasando. Puedes pegar un fragmento de csv en la pregunta, o suministrar un enlace a un almacén externo (tipo OneDrive, GDrive, Dropbox, etc...) Por favor no pegues una imagen del dataframe que no serviría de nada.

Comment: Claro, de este sitio: https://datamexico.org/es/profile/geo/san-nicolas-de-los-garza#seguridad-publica-denuncias Es la primera gráfica sobre denuncias, puedes descargar el CSV.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que la cadena que quieres reemplazar contiene paréntesis, y debido a que has incluido el parámetro `regex=True`, esos paréntesis tienen un significado especial (creación de grupos dentro de la regexp).

Lo más sencillo es que pongas `regex=False` y ya funcionará correctamente la sustitución:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("Denuncias-segun-bien-afectado-en-San-Nicolas-de-los-GarzaClic-en-el-grafico-para-seleccionar.csv")

df['Affected Legal Good'].replace(
    {'Patrimonio': 'Heritage', 'Familia':'Family', 'Libertad y Seguridad Sexual':'Sexual Freedom and Safety', 
     'Sociedad':'Society', 'Vida e Integridad Corporal':'Life and Bodily Integrity', 'Libertad Personal':'Personal Freedom', 
     'Otros Bienes Jurídicos Afectados (Del Fuero Común)':'Other Affected Legal Assets (Common Jurisdiction)'}, 
     inplace=True, regex=False)

# Inspeccionemos valores diferentes en esa columna:
print(df["Affected Legal Good"].unique())
```

Resultado:

```
array(['Heritage', 'Family', 'Sexual Freedom and Safety', 'Society',
       'Life and Bodily Integrity', 'Personal Freedom',
       'Other Affected Legal Assets (Common Jurisdiction)'], dtype=object)
```

Como ves, no era problema de acentos por lo que supongo que tu otra pregunta ya no es relevante. De cualquier forma, la expresión que usaste para quitar acentos **sí** que estaba funcionando.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la solución.